# Passing an argument to a python script and opening a file

Tags: python

I've built a script that takes a filename as an argument and extracts all lines that match a certain pattern. Trouble is I can't open the filename - I keep getting :

```
"TypeError: coercing to unicode: need string or buffer"
```

It's complaining about the line `info = open(name, 'r')`.

Here's the code:

```
import re
import sys
print sys.argv[1:]

keyword = 'queued='
pattern = re.compile(keyword)

name = sys.argv[1:]
inf = open(name, 'r') 
outf = open("test.txt", 'w')

for line in inf:
    if pattern.search(line):
        outf.write(line)
```

And I call it with

```
`extract.py trunc.log`
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: which python version do you use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sys.argv[1:]` is a *list*, not a *string*.  When you slice a list, you get a list back -- even if you only take 1 element with the slice.  You need to give `open` a string.  Perhaps you wanted `sys.argv[-1]` (the last element)?

As a side note, the python standard library provides commandline parsing options -- One is the excellent [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) module which was introduced in python 2.7, but can be installed with very minimal effort on older python versions (I use it with python2.6 regularly).

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
name = sys.argv[1:]
```

makes `name` into a list of all arguments except the first. You mean:

```
name = sys.argv[1]
```

For real-world usage, you might want to look into [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse).

Answer (score 1):

`sys.argv` returns a **list** of the command line arguments. You may want to loop on each element of this list (but the first one):

```
with open("test.txt", "w") as outf:
    for name in sys.argv[1:]:
        with open(name, 'r') as inf:
            ...
```

Note that we open `test.txt` (your output file) first, then we try to open each file passed as argument of your script. You probably want to throw a `try... except` around the `open(name,'r')` just in case (the file can't be opened).

Answer (score 1):

you're better of with <del>[optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html)</del> [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html)

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                   help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                   const=sum, default=max,
                   help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.accumulate(args.integers))
```

<del>python 3.2 has [an alternative (argparse)](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html).</del>

Comment: Why the deprecated `optparse` in lieu of the more modern and flexible `argparse`?

Comment: `argparse` is included with python 2.7 ... It is also trivial to install on prior versions :  `easy_install argparse` does the trick for me.

Comment: ah okay, the documentation says it was added in 3.2 ("New in version 3.2")

Comment: It might not have been in 3.0 or 3.1 -- Those were developed in parallel with python 2.6.  But it's still trivial to "backport", it's a better package, and it's the future.  No sense using something inferior which will be removed later if it's trivial to install today ...